# RandomizedSearchCV returning no score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've created a pipeline to run my preprocessor and manage missing values etc. but I am stuck when I try using the RandomizedSearchCV.
The normal GridsearchCV works fine.

It is a supervised learning style and a classification learning task, predicting/classifying a binary target (1/0).

This is my model:

```
# Random Forest
RF = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, criterion='gini', max_depth=None, 
                            min_samples_split=2, min_samples_leaf=1, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
                            max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None, random_state=1337)
```

And this is where I set up the Pipeline and try to get the score, however this doesn't work probably.

```
pipeline_RF = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
        #('pca', pca),
        ('rf', RF)                          
])

print("\n------------ Randomized Search (Random Forest) ------------")

param_distributions = {
    'rf__n_estimators':  np.random.randint(1, 200, 10),
    'rf__max_depth': np.random.randint(1, 100, 10),
    'rf__min_samples_split': np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 10, endpoint=True),      
    'rf__min_samples_leaf':  np.linspace(0.1, 0.5, 5, endpoint=True),
    'rf__criterion': ['entropy'],
    'rf__max_features': ['auto']
}

rscv = RandomizedSearchCV(pipeline_RF, param_distributions=param_distributions, cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5), 
                          scoring="recall", n_iter=2, refit=True, n_jobs=-1, random_state=1337, return_train_score=True, verbose=10)

rscv.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("\nBest parameter (CV score=%0.3f):" % rscv.best_score_)
print("\Best Hyperparameters: ", rscv.best_params_)

y_pred = rscv.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)
print("\nPrecision, Recall, F1 and Support: ", precision_recall_fscore_support(y_test, y_pred, average='binary'))
```

The error message is the following, but not helping me much:

```
------------ Randomized Search (Random Forest) ------------
Fitting 5 folds for each of 2 candidates, totalling 10 fits

[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 2 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   1 tasks      | elapsed:    4.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   4 tasks      | elapsed:    8.1s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  10 out of  10 | elapsed:   18.4s finished


Best parameter (CV score=0.000):
\Best Hyperparameters:  {'rf__n_estimators': 135, 'rf__min_samples_split': 0.30000000000000004, 'rf__min_samples_leaf': 0.30000000000000004, 'rf__max_features': 'auto', 'rf__max_depth': 51, 'rf__criterion': 'entropy'}

Precision, Recall, F1 and Support:  (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, None)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:1272: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))
```

It looks like it set the hyperparameters (even though they seem to be the same each time I run it).

Does anybody have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Look closely at the warning message; there are some classes which you model does not predict, making the respective metrics undefined.

Comment: What's the class balance in `y_train`?

Comment: @BenReiniger Thanks for answering! The target variable is "success" with "No" having 32893 occurences and "Yes" only having "4176", therefore a 12,7% success rate. Is this what you were asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As desertnaut already pointed out in the comments, your model simply cannot predict the minority class. Your code on the other hand is alright. You can verify this the following way:

Based on your reply comment to BenReiniger, I created a dummy dataset to reproduce your situation:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=(32893+4176), n_classes=2, weights=[0.88, 0.12])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

This dataset has the same class imbalance and sample size as yours. When you run your code on this dataset, you will get the very same warning. Now, why is that? Let's check the outcome of `y_pred` as a `pandas` dataframe:

```
print(pd.DataFrame(y_pred).astype('category').describe())

# output
count   7414
unique     1
top        0
freq    7414
```

As you can see, the model predicted one class only. In such a case, the precision score for the positive class, defined as `tp / (tp + fp)`, is undefined as there is a division by zero involved. This is also why your warning tells you:

```
Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
```

You should be able to verify this on your own dataset. Also, if you use another scoring function like `accuracy_score`, you should be able to see your code running with no warnings or errors and returning the score as expected. Some metrics are simply undefined if the model does not predict any positive class.

This should clarify things. In conclusion, your code is alright. But your model is not trained well enough for the prediction task and you need to handle the class imbalance properly.

Comment: Thanks so much! 

This explanation helped me a alot understanding what is going wrong!
Using accuracy scoring gives me a result like you mentioned - but especially because of the imbalance - I doubt this is the right scoring method for my problem.

I will do some research on handling the class imbalance and I hope this also improves some of my other models I am practicing with (These models however work with f1/recall/precision scoring). I thought using StratifiedKFold will help me tackle this issue, but it seems like this isn't enough?

Thanks again for your detailed answer!

Comment: Just to clarify: the accuracy score was mentioned to support the point that, in general, everything works as expected. The accuracy is definitely a misleading performance metric in cases of high class imbalance. You are using suitable metrics. But the demonstrated outcome is to be expected and legitimate. There is nothing wrong with the code or the metrics you used. But your model building process needs to be improved.

Comment: I've got that and read somewhat into the topic of imbalanced classes. By using upsampling for my success feature I've not only been able to get my RandomizedSearchCV working, but I have also been able to drastically improve my other models (running with GridSearchCV) - now achieving f1 scores of about 92% (previously ~55%). I tested this with a still imbalanced training set.

You really somehow enlightend me in what my problem was and I will definetly take more care of imbalanced classes in the future.

Could you maybe help me understand why simply using StratifiedKFold doesn't fix this?

Comment: Good job...! ;)

Comment: Since you asked about it: when splitting data, stratification preserves the original class distribution in each split. This won't help your model learn more effectively. But it is very important for your model evaluation. Because, if the test set did not adequately represent the original problem, your tests are basically meaningless. This is btw why you should only resample the training and not the test set. You'd otherwise invalidate your results. So, be careful. I hope this helps and concludes it. We are spamming the comments section ;)

Comment: Thanks again to both you and desertnaut for elaborating and helping me out! I will definitely only resample the training set to train my model and test it afterwards taking the unchanged test set. Thank you! :)